# How can I create bookmarks in an mp3 file?

Tags: software-recommendation, vlc, mp3

Is there a software application that allows me to bookmark a timestamp with some tag in the play of an mp3 file? For example, I want to bookmark places in an audio book, corresponding to the bookmarks/outlines of its pdf file, to signify the beginning of chapters and sections and any place that interests me.

Can I do that in VLC player? Or which software application would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

[Banshee](https://www.banshee-project.org/about/features/) can and afaik it is the only one.

> Utilities
>
> Bookmarks
>
> Set a bookmark on any song, video, or podcast so you can return to it later.

but it is 1 mark where you can return to and it only works with Banshee.

Comment: Thanks. https://www.websitepulse.com/tools/china-firewall-test shows it is not accessible

Comment: Are the created bookmarks stored inside mp3 files or in the software application?

Comment: in the software: as stated it only works when using banshee

Comment: Can other formats of audio or video  files store bookmarks?